# How to detect when Firebase servercall is DONE

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Google Firebase to load data into my app. I am doing an initial load that gets the last 40 chat messages like so:

```
firebase.database().ref('/messages').limitToLast(40).once('value', function(messages) {
    traverseMessages(messages.val());
});
```

Then traverse:

```
// traverse messages function
function traverseMessages(obj) {
   for (var prop in obj) {
      var message = obj[prop].message;
      var chatUser = obj[prop].username;

      // populate function with data
      createChatElements(chatUser, message);
   };
};
```

Create HTML elements:

```
// build html for chat elements
function createChatElements(chatUser, message) {

    // build HTML
    var chatHTML = '<div class="chat-message">';
    chatHTML += '<h5 class="chat-message-username">' + chatUser +     '</h5>';
    chatHTML += '<p class="chat-message-message">' + message + '</p>';
    chatHTML += '</div>';

    // function to append chat
    appendChatToStaging(chatHTML);
};
```

The elements are appended to `<div class="chat-staging"></div>`

When all of the messages have been appended I want to trigger an event with a function.

But I can't seem to figur out how to detect wether all of the messages have been appended because I don't know how many there are in the database. Sometimes there are less than 40.

So I want to: detect when the call to the server is done and how many messages have been retrieved. But how?!

Comment: Hey Jabba, let me know if my answer was helpful or if you still have any doubts. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, It didn't really work. Was getting weird results. Maybe because of my own messy code. I have figured it out another way now :) Thanks for thinking with me though!

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `traverseMessages` the call from firebase has already finished. So if you want to call something right after appending all your data you can do it right after your `for` loop in `traverseMessages`.

Also, if you want to know how many objects firebase returned you can go with the following:

```
Object.keys(messages.val()).length
```